# So I have the following question, dont have much info on class notes and not sure how to tackle it, any suggestions, any help?

Tags: economics, bayesian, nash-equilibrium

A seller has a single item for sale (which she values at zero). There are
two potential buyers. The seller decides to use the following auction
format to sell the object: each bidder submits a sealed bid; the highest
bidder wins  in the event of a tie the winner is chosen by a coin
toss; the winner pays the average of the two bids. The two bidders are
risk-neutral with independent, private values drawn from the Uniform
distribution on $[0,1]$.
Show that it is a Bayesian Nash equilibrium for each bidder to use the
following bidding function:

$$B_i (v_i) =\dfrac{2}{v_i}, \ \  \ \ i = 1, 2$$

Answer (score 0):

If the other guy's valuation is $x$, then he bids $2/x$. We have to check if given the other guys strategy I bid $2/v$ when my value is $v$.
Let us define the inicator function $I(b,x)$=[1 if I bid higher, 0 otherwise].

$\\$ Note that this is 1 for $b>(2/x)$ or $x>2/b$.

Expected profit by bidding $b$ is
$ \\=  \int_0^1 (v-b/2-1/x)I(b,x)dx
\\= \int_0^{\frac2b} (v-b/2-1/x)I(b,x)dx+\int_{\frac2b}^1 (v-b/2-1/x)I(b,x)dx
\\=\int_{\frac2b}^1 (v-b/2-1/x)dx  
\\= (v-b/2)(1-2/b)+log(2/b)$

You can now try differentiating this w.r.t $b$ and then write b as a function of $v$  check if $b^*=2/v$
From what I tried, it was not working out. But, this is how these problems are generally solved.

Comment: pffff thanks for your help but my maths level is not so high so high to read that, we havent dont integers at this class..